# Flutter - unit test for a stopwatch app using Stopwatch class

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing

There is a simple stopwatch application where I need to test that if I press the start button and then press it again after 3 minutes, for example, I see on the display (in a Text Widget) 00:03:000.

In comparison, the test below returns that only 46 seconds (which is sometimes 45 or 47) have elapsed.

```
  testWidgets('Widget - Test stopwatch start', (tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      const MaterialApp(
        home: MainScreen(),
      ),
    );

    final startBtnWidget = find.byKey(const Key('btnStartStop'));

    await tester.tap(startBtnWidget);
    await tester.pump(const Duration(minutes: 3));
    await tester.tap(startBtnWidget);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    final timerText = find.byKey(const Key('timerText'));
    expect(timerText, findsOneWidget);

    final text = timerText.evaluate().single.widget as Text;

    expect(text.data, '00:03:000');
  });
```

... and the result:

```
Expected: '00:03:000'
  Actual: '00:00:046'
   Which: is different.
          Expected: 00:03:000
            Actual: 00:00:046
                        ^
           Differ at offset 4
```

Comment: Please include the code that is being tested.

Comment: I've cut the substance out of the project and shared it here with the test: https://github.com/Adamsky-dev/swdebug

Answer (score 0):

[Flutter's `testWidgets` uses `fake_async`](https://medium.com/flutter/understanding-async-in-flutter-tests-a304a7604b3c), and as explained by the [`package:fake_async`](https://pub.dev/packages/fake_async) documentation:

> `FakeAsync` can't control the time reported by `DateTime.now()` or by
> the `Stopwatch` class, since they're not part of `dart:async`. However, if
> you create them using the [`clock`](https://pub.dev/packages/clock) package's [`clock.now()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/clock/latest/clock/Clock/now.html) or
> [`clock.stopwatch()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/clock/latest/clock/Clock/stopwatch.html) functions, `FakeAsync` will automatically override
> them to use the same notion of time as `dart:async` classes.

You will need to modify the code for your widgets to use `clock.stopwatch()` instead of `Stopwatch()`.

Comment: Hi @jamesdlin, thanks for your reply! Did you mean [this](https://pub.dev/packages/clock) package? This one really works. Technically, I just modified `Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch()` to `Stopwatch stopwatch = clock.stopwatch()` and the test shown above works.

However, if possible, I would be interested in a test that works for the Stopwatch class. Thanks in advance!
[Here is](https://github.com/Adamsky-dev/swdebug) the original code (still with the Stopwatch class).

Comment: @Adamsky You should read the links I provided in my answer.  Yes, that is the same package that I already linked to.  And as explained by [the article I linked to](https://medium.com/flutter/understanding-async-in-flutter-tests-a304a7604b3c), you can use [`LiveTestWidgetsFlutterBinding`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/LiveTestWidgetsFlutterBinding-class.html) to *not* run tests in a `FakeAsync` `Zone`, but that will mean that your tests have to run in realtime.  Using `clock.stopwatch()` is the better approach.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! I'm still a bit confused about this "async" and how to test it, but I'll try to work my way through it. Thanks again for the help (and the suggestions).